# How to calculate minutes between two dates excluding weekend and holidays?

Tags: sql-server

How can I calculate the Count of Minutes ( The minutes calulation is Monday 7AM to Friday 7PM)  between two dates from table (from the 1st row to the end) in SQL Server 2008R2?

I tried something like this, but it does not work

```
     DECLARE  @StartDate DateTime='2015-06-12 13:03:00'
     DECLARE @EndDate DateTime='2015-06-16 10:08:00'

        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) = 1
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR,8,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@StartDate),1))
        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) = 7
            set @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR,8,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@StartDate),2))


        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@EndDate) = 1
            SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR,19,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@EndDate),-2))
        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@EndDate) = 7
            SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR,19,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@EndDate),-1))

        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@StartDate) = 2 AND DATEPART(HH, @StartDate)<8
            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate))
        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@EndDate) = 6 AND DATEPART(HH, @EndDate)>8
            SET @EndDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 19, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate)) 

    Declare @WorkMin int  
    Set @WorkMin=DATEDIFF(MI,@StartDate,@EndDate)-(DATEDIFF(WEEK,@StartDate,@EndDate)*2880)

    Print @WorkMin ----Out put is 2705

    ---------Actual Minutes is 1985
```

Above code is calculating minutes Friday after 7 PM and Monday Before 7 AM.But I want to exclude those minutes.So Can any one help me on this?

Comment: SQL-Server or mysql or Oracle DB? Tags say mysql or Qoracle DB and your question asks for SQL-Server

Comment: Need only for sql server

Comment: not all countries have the same holidays

Comment: I want  to count hours from 8:00 am on Monday through to 7:00 pm on Friday, excluding Friday 7:01 pm to Monday 6:59 am

Answer (score 0):

I get 1985 minutes.  Honestly, I got this the first time I wrote the script following your rules, which I found quite amazing tbbh.

```
--Working week is 7AM Monday to 7PM Friday
--Get the start date
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20150612 13:03:00';

--If the start date is in the weekend period then move it forward to 7AM Monday
DECLARE @days INT = NULL;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 7 --Saturday
    SELECT @days = 2;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 1 --Sunday
    SELECT @days = 1;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 6 AND DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) > 19 --Friday after 7PM
    SELECT @days = 3;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = 2 AND DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) < 7 --Monday before 7AM
    SELECT @days = 0;
IF @days IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @StartDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @StartDate)) + DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @StartDate)) + DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @StartDate)) + ' 07:00');

--Get the end date
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20150616 10:08:00';

--If the end date is in the weekend period then move it back to 7PM Friday
SELECT @days = NULL;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 7 --Saturday
    SELECT @days = -1;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 1 --Sunday
    SELECT @days = -2;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 6 AND DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) > 19 --Friday after 7PM
    SELECT @days = 0;
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = 2 AND DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate) < 7 --Monday before 7AM
    SELECT @days = -3;
IF @days IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @EndDate)) + DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @EndDate)) + DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, @days, @EndDate)) + ' 19:00');

--Now calculate the raw minutes
DECLARE @Minutes INT;
SELECT @Minutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate);

--Work out how many complete weeks we have, then take this off the result
DECLARE @CompleteWeeks INT = 0;
SELECT @CompleteWeeks = DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate);
SELECT @Minutes = @Minutes - @CompleteWeeks * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20170421 19:00', '20170424 07:00'); --3600 minutes, we could just hardcode this

--Output
SELECT 'Start Date' AS metric, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @StartDate) AS [value]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'End Date', CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @EndDate)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Minutes', CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Minutes);
```

There's probably better ways to do this, but I basically broke the problem down into these steps:

- if the start date is in the "weekend period" then move it forward to Monday 7AM;
- if the end date is in the "weekend period" then move it backward to Friday 7PM;
- count the minutes between the adjusted dates;
- remove the "weekend period" minutes (i.e. the minutes from 7PM Friday to 7AM Monday) for each complete week we have left in the date ranges.  Due to my adjustments earlier, this should work.

I'm not sure that the start/ end bits work 100% as your example dates weren't very good examples (neither of them is in the weekend period).

I tried to follow a similar pattern to your script (which fundamentally doesn't work btw).

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't match. Based on my calculation, the value is 1265 minutes: 
[manual excel calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00gvQ.png)

And the code to produce (absent the summing) is below. It is based on a very specific version of a calendar table - which is a technique you should learn how to incorporate into your skillset. It is defined statically and contains just enough information to demonstrate this particular issue; I'll leave it to you to adapt it in a more generic fashion.

```
set nocount on;
declare @cal table (dt_start datetime not null, dt_end datetime not null); 
insert @cal(dt_start, dt_end) values 
('20150611 07:00', '20150611 19:00'), 
('20150612 07:00', '20150612 19:00'), -- friday
('20150615 07:00', '20150615 19:00'), 
('20150616 07:00', '20150616 19:00'), 
('20150617 07:00', '20150617 19:00'),
('20150618 07:00', '20150618 19:00');
select * from @cal order by dt_start;

declare @ps datetime, @pe datetime; 
set @ps = '20150612 13:03';
set @pe = '20150616 10:08';
select @ps as ps, @pe as pe; 

select --@ps as [start], @pe as [end], 
t.*, 
case when t.dt_start < @ps then @ps else t.dt_start end as s1, 
case when t.dt_end > @pe then @pe else t.dt_end end as e1,
datediff(minute, 
case when t.dt_start < @ps then @ps else t.dt_start end,   
case when t.dt_end > @pe then @pe else t.dt_end end ) as calc
from @cal as t
where t.dt_start <= @pe and t.dt_end >= @ps
order by t.dt_start
;
```

And you first stated that your work period was 7am - 7pm, yet you later said 8am - 7pm. I still don't quite see how your calculation works, but the one hour difference using 8am doesn't account for the difference.